# Access SQL Server from Solaris

Tags: sql-server, odbc, solaris

I found out about the freeTDS which can be used here, but there are doubts about its stability in the production environment. Is there any other way to interactive with MSSQL Server from Solaris besides using ODBC driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know of any other way.

We're using unixODBC + freeTDS + DBD::Sybase in a production environment.
It can be fiddly setting it up, but we have no problems with stability.

It is possible to use FreeTDS directly and bypass unixODBC.

Comment: Great to hear that freeTDS is stable. It is the simplest way. which version of freeTDS are you guys using?

Comment: We're using 0.64.
Configuration was: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-msdblib